# How do I just select a single color for the scatter.mapbox function and print the maps side by side

Tags: python, plot, latitude-longitude

```
def generateSeasons(season, color = "blue", color1 = "orange", color2 = "red", cj=cj):
  cj2123 = cj.loc[cj["Season"] == season].reset_index()
  color_scale = [(0, color1), (1, color2)]

  fig1 = px.scatter_mapbox(cj2123,
                          lat="latitude",
                          lon="longtitude",
                          color=color,
                          zoom=15,
                          height=500,
                          width=500)
  
  fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(cj2123,
                          lat="latitude",
                          lon="longtitude",
                          hover_name="length",
                          hover_data=["length"],
                          color="length",
                          color_continuous_scale=color_scale,
                          zoom=15,
                          height=500,
                          width=500)

  fig1.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
  fig1.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
  fig1.show()

  fig2.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
  fig2.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
  fig2.show()
```

I want fig1 to print out just the points on the map and I want fig2 to print out print out the points on the map and the color is based on the length of a certain variable. I want to be able to set color for fig1 to show different color for different seasons. Also, I want to print the figures side by side, right now they are printing below each other.

I tried creating an array with the elements being the same color. This did not change the color but only added a label on the hover with a color name

```
colord = [color] * len(cj2123.index)

  fig1 = px.scatter_mapbox(cj2123,
                          lat="latitude",
                          lon="longtitude",
                          
                          color=colord,
                         
                          zoom=15,
                          height=500,
                          width=500)
```